# I cannot understand why TypeScript is not throwing an error here

Tags: typescript

I expect an error to be thrown in the following snippet, telling me that `b.resDetails is possibly undefined`, but no such error is thrown. Can I please get an explanation on this behavior ? I'm really confused.

```html
type BasicDetails = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  resDetails?: ResidentialDetails;
};

type ResidentialDetails = {
  address: string;
  state: string;
  city: string;
};

const b: BasicDetails = {
  name: "Ronit",
  age: 22,
};

console.log(b.resDetails.address);
```

Comment: That's what, since `b` is assigned the type `BasicDetails`, where `resDetails` is optional, shouldn't TypeScript throw an error here telling me that `resDetails` is possibly `undefined` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable this behaviour. In you tsconfig.json, make sure that `strictNullChecks` is enabled.